# PowerLevel10k and ColorLS symbols are not showing up, How to Fix This

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

OS version and name: macOS 11.2

Hyper.app version: 3.0.2

I was trying to get ZSH working with Hyper but then when I try to use PowerLevel10k and ColorLS, the icons don’t show up and instead are boxes, I tried using different fonts but I believe I am not doing it correctly because it either makes the text smaller or doesn't change anything

Comment: I never used Hyper, but if the themes look fine in a zsh in the nomal Terminal app, my feeling is that this is specific to Hyper, and I would use _hyper_ as a tag, and post this question on [su], since it is more related to configuration than programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Caskaydia Cove Nerd Font, and remember to update your hyper configuration file. It's gonna look like the following line:

```js
fontFamily: '"CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font Mono", monospace',
```

Comment: Download font from: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.1.0/CascadiaCode.zip

Comment: You may need to restart the configuration wizard: run `p10k configure`

Comment: how do I set up this font after download? Where should the given configuration go? Thanks!

Comment: @PrasannjeetSingh After downloading the font, proceed to install it. For most operating systems, right-click on the font file, then select "Open." An option to install should be visible; simply click on "Install."

To configure Hyper Terminal settings, open Hyper Terminal and press "Cmd + ," (for macOS) or "Ctrl + ," (for other operating systems). This action will open the `.hyper.js` configuration file where you can customize various settings according to your preferences.